# Using Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 server and Eclipse EE: servlet won't run a class file

Tags: java, html, tomcat

Clicking the submit button on my form produces a save dialog box (asking me to save the .class file that is supposed to run as called from POST) instead of a new page with the form partially filled out.

As stated above I am trying to use Tomcat 7.0.40 with my web application called Demonstration. I have been programming the quite simple pages in Eclipse then compiling them and setting up my own .war file for Tomcat. This didn't work after many, many tries so I let Eclipse do the construction of the .war file for me. Still didn't work.

Here is what I think are the relevant pieces of code.

The first file that runs is this HTML stored as webapps\Demonstration\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SurveyMark.css">
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>SurveyMark - Input Job</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="job_input_form" action="JobMade" method=POST>

<h1><img id="logo" alt="TJH Logo" src="logo_small.jpg" align="middle"><b> - 
SurveyMark - Input Job INDEX.HTML</b></h1>

<div id="job_div" style="width:250px;float:left">
    <h3>Job Details</h3>
  <label for="job_number">Job Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="job_number" id="job_number">
  <label for="addendum">Addendum</label>
  <input type="text" name="addendum" id="addendum">
  <label for="development_name">Development Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="development_name" id="development_name">
  <label for="job_type">Job Type</label>
  <input type="text" name="job_type" id="job_type">
  <label for="date_recieved">Date Recieved</label>
  <input type="text" name="date_recieved" id="date_recieved">
</div>
<div id="job_location_div" style="width:250px;float:left">
    <h3>Job Location</h3>
  <label for="unit_number">Unit Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="unit_number" id="unit_number">
  <div id="legal_street_number_div" style="width:120px;float:left">
........
........Lots more fields all on the same page, displaying properly
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Add Job">
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Which attempts to POST's to the following file \webapps\Demonstration\WEB-INF\classes\Demonstration\JobMade.class
(That compiles from this JobMade.java file)

```
package Demonstration;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;

@WebServlet("/JobMade")
public class JobMade extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //String title = "Job Data that has Been Entered";
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                    "<html>\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"       href=\"SurveyMark.css\">" +
                    "<meta charset=\"ISO-8859-1\">" +
                    "<title>SurveyMark - Input Job JOBMADE     FILE</title>" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    "<form id=\"job_input_form\"     action=\"AddedJob.html\" method=\"post\">" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Job\">" +
                    "<h1><img id=\"logo\" alt=\"TJH Logo\"     src=\"logo_small.jpg\" align=\"middle\"> - " +
                    "SurveyMark - Added Job as Follows</h1>");
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
            out.println("<TR><TD>" + paramName + "\n<TD>");
            String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
            if (paramValues.length == 1) {
                String paramValue = paramValues[0];
                if (paramValue.length() == 0)
                    out.print("<I>No Value</I>");
                else
                    out.print(paramValue);
            } else {
                out.println("<UL>");
                for(int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                    out.println("<LI>" + paramValues[i]);
                }
                out.println("</UL>");
                }
        }
        out.println("</TABLE>\n</BODY></HTML");
        }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }


    /**
     * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

 }
```

I have lloked at the catalina log files and can't find anything untoward but if there is something specific that would help I am all ears.

Here is the brief yet important web.xml file stored under the WEB-INF directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-    app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Demonstration</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You did not map that servlet anywhere..? Neither in the web.xml file, nor using an annotation...

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus sorry for not including my @WebServlet("/myServlet") or @WebServlet("/JobMade") I have had many revisions of this code over the past 24hrs and hadn't made it reflect one of the many variations that I thought might work. Code is updated to reflect the mapping that I have had inplace at one point and recieved the same result. Cheers, for pointing it out.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus you were right, even though I had tried about a million and one ways to map it, I apparently didn't try the right one. If you make your comment an answer I will tick it for you, thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not map that servlet anywhere. Neither in the web.xml file, nor using an annotation.